# WPF Combobox XML binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I haven't been able to find something that works for the particualr case of XML binding I'm trying to do.

I have the following snippet of xml:

I want to bind the type attribute to a combobox on a usercontrol, but have the list of selectable values driven by a list on the usercontrol.

On my usercontrol, I create the list of possible values:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="HealingComponentTypes" Type="sys:String">
        <sys:String>Absolute</sys:String>
        <sys:String>AbsolutePercent</sys:String>
        <sys:String>RelativePercent</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then i bind them to the combobox

```
<GroupBox DataContext="{Binding XPath=FieldHealingComponent}"  Header="Field Use" Height="328" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="231,2,0,0" Name="groupBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
            <Grid>
                <GroupBox Header="HP Healing Component" Height="101" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,0" Name="HPFieldUseGroup" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192">
                    <Grid>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource HealingComponentTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=HP/@type}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,49,0,0" Name="MPBattleUseType" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" />
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
           </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
```

The problem is that this doesn't bind the values. I see the three possibilities in the combobox drop down, but regardless of what I pick, it isn't reflected back into the xml. Similarly, the initial value isn't being shown in the combobox even when set. I know the base datacontext is correct because I have a label in the groupbox

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=HP/@amount}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,16,6,0" Name="HPFieldHealingAmount" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" />
```

and it displays amount correctly. I'm certain it's jsut me not knowing how to properly set the binding. I've tried numerous suggestions that showed when I googled for this, but none of them worked. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Mode=TwoWay in the binding?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a converter? I believe the type of the bound attribute is not of type string and you will require an `IValueConverter` to correctly read and update your XML.